# Importing pyFileMaker complains about EXPAT library

Tags: python, filemaker, expat-parser

I've just downloaded pyFileMaker. I copied the directory `PyFileMaker` into the dir `Lib` under Python31 directory, but when I simply include the module `FMServer` with this line:

```
from PyFileMaker import FMServer
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyFileMaker import FMServer
  File "C:\Python31\lib\PyFileMaker\__init__.py", line 17
    print "Unable to load the EXPAT library. You need to have it installed"
```

I checked whether the module expat exists and, infact, it exists. How can I fix this?

Comment: +1 imho the op does not merit a downvote without reason, especially being a newcomer

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can see the error happened not in the import, but in the `print` statement. (I.e. there probably was an error in import too, but it was intercepted.) The problem is that `PyFileMaker` is written for Python 2.x (their site says 2.4 is the minimal version), while you're using Python 3, and v3 *is not compatible* with v2.x.

I'd suggest switching to Python v2.7 (which is the primary version at the moment anyway). If you really want to use v3, you might try to convert the file with the `2to3` converter, but there's no guarantee it's going to work.